# Unterminated String Constant on Javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, mandrill

I'm using a Response.Write in ASP to send an e-mail via Javascript using the Mandrill API, I've already checked this code for at least 5 times and the syntax looks right to me, I don't know why this error is being reported.

```
if err.number = 0 then
Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"" type=""text/javascript"">
    $.ajax({
    type: “POST”,
    url: “https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json”,
    data: {
      ‘key’: ‘MYAPIKEY’,
      ‘message’: {
        ‘from_email’: ‘MAIL’,
        ‘to’: [
            {
              ‘email’: ‘MAIL’,
              ‘name’: ‘ABC’,
              ‘type’: ‘to’
            },
          ],
        ‘autotext’: ‘true’,
        ‘subject’: ‘TEST’,
        ‘html’: ‘TEST’
      }
    }
   }).done(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
   });
  </script>")
end if
```

I'd appreciate some help since I'm a beginner.

Comment: Taking a stab in the dark but I assume the odd quote marks probably are causing the issue (or will cause an issue in the future). Replace `“` and `‘` with either `'` or an escaped `"` (escaped to not interfere with your `Response.Write` call in ASP). On a slightly different note, I assume though the double `"` in your script tag are for escaping yeah?

Comment: Are you returning that script to a browser for execution? If that's the case, you *really* don't want to be exposing your Mandrill API Key in that manner.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the line continuation character `_` for multiple lines in the same string in ASP. If you want the output of the `response.write` formatted, you need to use `vbcrlf` to output a newline.

I have replaced the `“` in your code with `"`

```
<%
if err.number = 0 then
Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"" type=""text/javascript"">" & vbcrlf &_
"    $.ajax({" & vbcrlf &_
"    type: ""POST""," & vbcrlf &_
"    url: ""https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json""," & vbcrlf &_
"    data: { " & vbcrlf &_
"      'key': 'MYAPIKEY'," & vbcrlf &_
"      'message': { " & vbcrlf &_
"        'from_email': 'MAIL',"& vbcrlf &_
"        'to': [" & vbcrlf &_
"            {" & vbcrlf &_
"              'email': 'MAIL'," & vbcrlf &_
"              'name': 'ABC'," & vbcrlf &_
"              'type': 'to'" & vbcrlf &_
"            }," & vbcrlf &_
"          ]," & vbcrlf &_
"        'autotext': 'true', "& vbcrlf &_
"        'subject': 'TEST'," & vbcrlf &_
"        'html': 'TEST'" & vbcrlf &_
"      }" & vbcrlf &_
"    }" & vbcrlf &_
"   }).done(function(response) {" & vbcrlf &_
"     console.log(response);" & vbcrlf &_
"   });" & vbcrlf &_
"  </script>")
end if
%>
```